# Is the set $A$ non-empty, closed, bounded? convex? Prove your claims formally.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $A = \left \{ (x_{1},x_{2}): x_{1} \geq 0, x_{2} \geq 0), x_{1}+2x_{2} \leq 1, x_{2} \geq x_{1} \right \}$.

**Non-empty.** $A$ is non-empty. The points $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $(1,0)$ satisfy the conditions $x_{1} \geq 0$, $x_{2} \geq 0$, $x_{1}+2x_{2} \leq 1, x_{2} \geq x_{1}$ and are contained in the set $A$.

**Closed.** $A$ is closed. We need to show that it contains all its boundary points. So $$B = \begin{Bmatrix}
(x_{1},x_{2}): &  &  &x_{1} \in [0,1]\Leftrightarrow x_{1} \geq 0 \\ 
 &  &  &x_{2} \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\Leftrightarrow x_{2} \geq 0 \\ 
 &  &  & x_{1}+2x_{2}=1,x_{1}\geq 0, x_{2}\geq 0\\ 
 &  &  & x_{2}= x_{1}, x_{1}\geq 0, x_{2} \geq 0
\end{Bmatrix}$$.

**Bounded.** $A$ is bounded. The definition of a bounded set: A set $E$ is a bounded set if $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}$ and a point $q \in X$ (metric space) such that $d(p,q) < M$.

So just pick $M=2$ and $(0,0)$ for $A$ to be bounded.

**Convex.** Let $(x_{1}, y_{1})$, $(x_{1}, y_{1}) in A$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

Assume $x_{1} \geq 0, x_{2} \geq 0, x_{1}+2x_{2} \leq 1, x_{2} \geq x_{1}$ $(x \in A)$.

Also assume, Assume $y_{1} \geq 0, y_{2} \geq 0, y_{1}+yx_{2} \leq 1, y_{2} \geq y_{1}$ $(y \in A)$.

So $\lambda x_{1} + (1-\lambda) y_{1} \geq 0$ and $\lambda x_{2} + (1-\lambda) y_{2} \geq 0$.

Next, start from $\lambda x_{1} + (1-\lambda)2y_{1} + (1-\lambda) 2(y_{1}+y_{2}) \implies \lambda (x_{1} + x_{2}) + (1-\lambda)2 (y_{1} + y_{2}) \leq1$.

Also since $x_{2} - x_{1} \geq 0$ and $y_{2} - y_{1} \geq 0$, we have $$\lambda (x_{1} + x_{2}) + (1-\lambda) (y_{1}+y_{2}) \geq 0.$$

So $A$ is convex.

Are my "proofs" okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are OK, but closedness and convexity have a shorter proof if you observe $A$ is the intersection of $4$ closed half-planes (which are convex), he,ce their intersection is closed and convex.